# Why does mysql show 2 different results on 2 different servers for the same query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, explain

I have the same MySQL SQL statement running on 2 different databases (my local machine and my production machine).  The one on my local machine runs faster while the one on production is slow. Here are the EXPLAIN results on each.

**Local Machine**
[image]

**Production Machine**
[image]

I'd rather not post the exact query if I don't have to.

The only difference I can tell between the 2 is that my local machine is running version 5.6 while the production server is running 5.5.  Also, the data on my server is 3 days old which isn't many records. Specifically, I'm looking at row 2 of the explain where one type reads "ref" and the other reads "ALL" and there's a difference of over 28k rows being read.  The only difference between the 2 structures is the TimeModified field which isn't being used by the query

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough detail here to really give an answer - beyond the possible answer you already included in your question.

Comment: Why would people you have never met on the web believe that the data is the same on the two servers?  Clearly, the `explain` has different estimates/counts for the number of rows, so the explanation is that the data is different.

Comment: I'd say your databases are not the same then, either they have different table structures or they have different data -- and the size of your data can influence the execution plan.

Comment: Easy: You don't have an identical database, that is, the data within it.

Comment: With MySQL 5.5 and earlier, access to a derived table is always by a full scan; MySQL 5.5 *never* creates an index on derived table. But MySQL 5.6.3 can add an index to a derived table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 5.5 and earlier, a derived table *never* had indexes. The only way a derived table would be accessed was by a full scan.  (That's the **`ALL`** you see in the EXPLAIN output from the 5.5 server.)

With MySQL 5.6.3, MySQL has the ability to add an index to a derived table, which can improve performance. (Note  the name of the index: **`<auto_key1>`** in the EXPLAIN output from the 5.6 server).

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html

Comment: I'll upgrade the DB to 5.6 and see if that speeds up the query.

Comment: The upgrade did it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did put this as a comment first, but I think it also is the answer :-)

Your table structures might be identical, but your data probably isn't.

The number of rows in your tables will influence the execution plan.