# Why does the same query explain & perform so differently on a slave MySQL server than a master?

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-replication

I have a master MySQL server and a slave server. The data is replicated between them.

When I run this query on the master it's taking a number of hours; on the slave it takes seconds. The EXPLAIN plans back this up -- the slave examines far fewer rows than the master.

However, since the structure and data in these two databases are exactly the same (or should be at least), and they're both running the same version of MySQL (5.5.31 Enterprise), I don't understand what's causing this.

This is a similar symptom to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206444/why-does-mysql-show-2-different-results-on-2-different-servers-for-the-same-quer) (and others) but I don't think it's the same root cause because my two servers are in sync via MySQL replication, and the structure and data contents are (or should be) the same, and the OS & hardware resources are exactly the same on both servers -- they're VMWare and one is an image of the other.

I've verified that the number of rows in each table is exactly the same on both servers, and that their configurations are the same (except for the slave having directives pointing to the master). Short of going through the data itself to see if there are any differences I'm not sure what else I can check, and would be grateful for any advice.

The query is

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(cds.company_id))
 FROM   jobsmanager.companies c
 ,      jobsmanager.company_jobsmanager_settings cjs
 ,      jobsmanager.company_details_snapshot cds
 ,      vacancies v
 WHERE  c.company_id = cjs.company_id
 AND    cds.company_id = c.company_id
 AND    cds.company_id = v.jobsmanager_company_id
 AND    cjs.is_post_a_job = 'Y'
 AND    cjs.can_access_jobsmanager = 'Y'
 AND    cjs.account_status != 'suspended'
 AND    v.last_live BETWEEN cds.record_date - INTERVAL 365 DAY AND cds.record_date
 AND    cds.record_date BETWEEN '2016-01-30' AND '2016-02-05';
```

The master explains it like this, 3 million rows on the driving table, no key usage, and takes over an hour to return a result:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+----------------+---------+---------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys           | key            | key_len | ref                             | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+----------------+---------+---------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | ALL    | job_owner,last_live_idx | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                            | 3465433 |                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY        | 4       | s1jobs.v.jobsmanager_company_id |       1 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cds   | ref    | PRIMARY,company_id_idx  | company_id_idx | 4       | jobsmanager.c.company_id        |     538 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cjs   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,qidx,qidx2      | PRIMARY        | 4       | jobsmanager.c.company_id        |       1 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+----------------+---------+---------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

The slave uses a different driving table, uses an index, predicts more like 310,000 rows examined, and returns the result within a couple of seconds:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+---------+----------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys           | key       | key_len | ref                        | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+---------+----------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cds   | range  | PRIMARY,company_id_idx  | PRIMARY   | 3       | NULL                       | 310381 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY   | 4       | jobsmanager.cds.company_id |      1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cjs   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,qidx,qidx2      | PRIMARY   | 4       | jobsmanager.c.company_id   |      1 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | ref    | job_owner,last_live_idx | job_owner | 2       | jobsmanager.cds.company_id |     32 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+---------+----------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
```

I've run ANALYZE TABLE, OPTIMIZE TABLE and REPAIR TABLE ... QUICK on both servers to try to make them consistent, with no luck.

As a temporary solution I can run the queries on the slave, as they're in cron scripts and even if they take a long time on the slave they won't increase load on the master the way they do when they run on the master. However I'd be grateful for any other information on why these are different or what else I could check/revise which would explain such a drastic difference between the two. The only thing I can find is that the slave has more *free* memory, as it's in little use; would that alone account for this? If not what else?

```
$ ssh s1-mysql-01 free # master
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      99018464   98204624     813840          0     160752   55060632
-/+ buffers/cache:   42983240   56035224
Swap:      4095992    4095992          0
$ ssh s1-mysql-02 free # slave
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      99018464   80866420   18152044          0     224772   72575168
-/+ buffers/cache:    8066480   90951984
Swap:      4095992     206056    3889936
$
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: The only really big difference between the 2 explains is that on the master no index is used on the vacancies table. You could try place an index hint (force index) into the select on master to force the use of job_owner index. You can also try to run analyse table on all tables invovled in the above query on the master to make sure that the table and index stats are updated.

Comment: Ok thanks Shadow will do.

Comment: Have you forced it to refresh the indexes recently on one server? If the stats are out of date it could be mistakenly ignoring indexes. I would suggest trying to do an optimize table ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html ) on the master and see if that improves things.

Comment: Hi, thanks I'd run optimize & analyse already with no great difference. I've now revised it to force index (job_owner) as Shadow suggested and that's brought the master's EXPLAIN down to 310k rows, and it's now returning within a couple of seconds. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Shadow - What is `job_owner`?  It seems irrelevant.  @JeremyJones - please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames job_owner is an index's name. Apparently it is not irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only really big difference between the 2 explains is that on the master no index is used on the vacancies table.

You could try place an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) (force index) into the select on master to force the use of job_owner index.

You can also try to run [analyze table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html) on all tables involved in the above query on the master to make sure that the table and index stats are updated.

Comment: Adding FORCE INDEX job_owner to the query successfully changed the EXPLAIN plan on the master to be 310k rows, similar to the slave.

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same problem, but in my case slave was not using index.
Index hints (use index / force index) helped, but it's not good solution in this case. So I tried run analyze table on slave server, and it has fixed the problem:

```
ANALYZE NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLE tbl_name
```

Now both servers use correct indexes.

`NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG`  - needed in case when it's runing on replica.

Also `ANALYZE` should be executed during the low peak of load or a maintenance window, othervise you can get many user queries stuck in `Waiting for table flush` state.